# How to write the JSON inside <span> tag in c# file?

Tags: c#, html, json

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<span data-date-conv='{"+"dstring"+":"+eventPage.StartDate.ToString()+","+"pattern"+":"+"P0"+"}'></span>");
```

Above code is not properly rendered (incorrect Format), It displays as:

```
<span data-date-conv="{dstring:4/25/2017 12:00:00 AM,pattern:p0}"></span>
```

When we write in HTML file then it displays as (correct format):

```
<span data-date-conv='{"dstring":"4/25/2017 12:00:00 AM","pattern":"p0"}'></span>
```

Comment: Could you please try `sb.Append("<span data-date-conv='{"+"'dstring'"+":'"+eventPage.StartDate.ToString()+"',"+"'pattern'"+":"+"'P0'"+"}'></span>");`

Comment: you should put a backslash before ' and " like \' and \"

Comment: <span data-date-conv="{" dstring':4="" 25="" 2017="" 12:00:00="" am,'pattern'‌​:p0}'=""></span>
I got this output which is not correct...
Any other soln please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it something like this

```
sb.Append("<span data-date-conv='{\"dstring:\"" + eventPage.StartDate.ToString() + "\",\"pattern:\"P0\"}'></span>");
```

Literals are how you hard-code strings into C# programs. There are two types of string literals in C# - regular string literals and verbatim string literals. In particular, `"` itself, `\`, and carriage return (CR) and line feed (LF)) need to be "escaped" to be represented in the string. To obtain a " within the string itself, you need to write "". Verbatim string literals are distinguished by having an @ before the opening quote.

Taken from [Strings in C# and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)

and thus you can also try it like

```
sb.Append(@"<span data-date-conv='{""dstring:""" + eventPage.StartDate.ToString() + @""",""pattern"":""P0""}'></span>");
```

Comment: sb.Append(@"<span data-date-conv='{""dstring"":""" + eventPage.StartDate.ToString() + @""",""pattern"":""P0""}'></span>");

After dstring is modified. Double quotes are added after the dstring.

Answer (score 1):

When we compare the first string with the second one, the difference is the quotation marks (") that encapsulate the keys and the values. So, you can achieve what you want by manually applying them, while escaping with '\' character, to your string like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<span data-date-conv='{"+"\"dstring\""+":\""+eventPage.StartDate.ToString()+"\","+"\"pattern\""+":"+"\"P0\""+"}'></span>");
```